# Forcing ignoring errors from ADODB to Excel VBA

Tags: vba, error-handling

I don't know if this is possible, but I figured I'd ask.

Is there an equivalent to `On Error GoTo Next` for ADODB connections in Excel VBA?

I have a stored procedure I'm calling using an ADODB.Command object.  The problem is, if any one statement in that stored procedure throws an error, the entire process gets shut down.  Yes, that's appropriate in some cases, but in my case, it's not a big deal, I'd just like it to continue executing the rest of the stored procedure anyway.

`On Error GoTo 0` shows the SQL error message and gives options to "End" or "Debug".

`On Error Resume Next` skips the SQL error message, but silently cancels the SQL command and moves the next VBA statement.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I've had a request for my code.  I'm not sure it will help you much, but here:

```
On Error GoTo 0

ServerConnection.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties="DRIVER=SQL Native Client;Trusted_Connection=Yes;SERVER=DBServer;DATABASE=Database";"

Dim SqlCommand As ADODB.Command
Set SqlCommand = New ADODB.Command

With SqlCommand
    .ActiveConnection = ServerConnection
    .CommandText = "EXEC CacheTables @CacheTableType1=True"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Execute
End With

ServerConnection.Close

Set SqlCommand = Nothing
Set ServerConnection = Nothing
```

I don't really control the stored procedure, unfortunately, but the reason it's throwing errors is that the person who wrote it used RAISERROR statements to tell the user where the execution is up to.  This is fine in SQL Server, which understands the "Priority" flag and hence continues executing, but VBA appears to consider all errors to be the same importance.

Comment: please post your code...

Comment: @Mitch Done, though I'm not sure it will help much.

Comment: " the person who wrote it used RAISERROR statements to tell the user where the execution is up to. " - eeek!

Comment: could you wrap the offending stored proc. in another that contains TRY/CATCH and simply 'eats' the RAISERROR progress statements?

Comment: @Mitch, the problem with TRY/CATCH is that it ignores severity less than or equal to 10 ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

Because the processing of your stored procedure is all taking place on your DB server, you would have to have some kind of error handling inside the stored procedure. For example a Try/Catch block in your TSQL if you are using Sql Server:

```
BEGIN TRY
     { sql_statement | statement_block }
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
END CATCH
[ ; ]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Alternatively you could break up your sprocs into logical divisions and surround each call with `On Error GoTo Next` blocks in VBA. This latter option is a pretty dirty hack though, I believe.